# Eclipse RCP vs Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm beginning to develop a GUI based plugin and doing my homework by doing plugin guides ect. But I'm noticing different guides out there for Eclipse plugins and Eclipse RCP plugins. However I can't get a straight forward difference between the two so am wondering which route I should be going down and should I be using standard Eclipse or be using Eclipse for RCP development?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to extend the Eclipse IDE, as in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html), a simple classic Eclipse is enough to develop "[Eclipse plugins](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/firstplugin.htm)".

> The Eclipse platform is structured as a core runtime engine and a set of additional features that are installed as platform plug-ins.
>   Plug-ins contribute functionality to the platform by **contributing to pre-defined extension points**. The workbench UI is contributed by one such plug-in.
>   When you start up the workbench, you are not starting up a single Java program. You are activating a platform runtime which can dynamically discover registered plug-ins and start them as needed.
>
> When you want to provide code that extends the platform, you do this by defining system extensions in your plug-in.
>   The platform has a well-defined set of **extension points** - places where you can hook into the platform and contribute system behavior.
>   From the platform's perspective, your plug-in is no different than basic plug-ins like the resource management system or the workbench itself.

---

But if you want to do an *independent* application, based on the Eclipse *platform*, then it is an [RCP ("Rich Client Platform")](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP), and you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html).

> Eclipse-based applications which are not primarily used as software development tools are called Eclipse RCP applications.
>   An Eclipse 4 RCP application typically uses the base components of the Eclipse platform and adds additional application specific components.

You would need then an "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" (from the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed definitions, cleared the differences up for me :)!